why recent angular project build outputs individual component css source map
I generated a new Angular 18 project from scratch and brought over my components to take advantage of new option defaults and settings. I'm happy I did so, but I noticed that it now seems to be producing source maps for my individual component specified CSS:

modal.component.css.map and task-list.component.css.map are the two examples shown here. I didn't get these in my prior build process (originating from around Angular 8 or 9 I think), but the project and styles worked as expected so I don't know what has changed and how to interpret what I see.
As I use plain CSS and not SCSS or others, I don't really need the styles source maps to begin with. I noticed these as Edge developer tools was trying to download them, and it wasn't specifying the correct URL so they were 404.
I'm considering turning off source maps for styles as I don't need them anyway. I'd just like to understand these changes.


As I use plain CSS and not SCSS or others, I don't really need the styles source maps to begin with. I noticed these as Edge developer tools was trying to download them, and it wasn't specifying the correct URL so they were 404.

Could be a caching issue, where the index.html is cached by the browser and it looks for the wrong .map file.

I'm considering turning off source maps for styles as I don't need them anyway. I'd just like to understand these changes.

Even if you use plain CSS or SASS, the concept of sourceMaps will remain the same. It helps the developer debug minified/uglified code, directly on the browser easily. This is ok for development mode and not for production. If you check the styles inspector and click on one of the source style links, it will directly open the style.
When it was added, I would guess 6 years ago, looking at the source code it's from Angular 6
Estimated Commit
But it does not really matter, since it's designed to enhance developer debugging and checking source code and on production should always be disabled.

thanks for your answer. I've cleared caches multiple times, angular build cache, browser cache (Edge has cache disabled when Developer Tools open), etc. Incidentally, I made some other changes and the Edge request for those source maps is now "valid" as it fixed some deployment paths and thus they are no longer 404.
